# SSIS execution - INSERT permission was denied on the object 'operation_os_sys_info', database 'SSISDB', schema 'internal'

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Please help. Users are getting the error below when trying to execute an SSISDB package from the Integration Services Catalogue. The users have READ and EXEECUTE on the folder and the package.

Now, I could give them WRITE to the table, but that just seems wrong.

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "set_system_informations":
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'operation_os_sys_info', database 'SSISDB', schema 'internal'.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQuerySmi(Boolean sendToPipe)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.SystemInformations.SetSystemInformations(SqlInt64 operationId)
>
> . (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 6522)

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between SQL Server 2012 SSISDB and v.Current with regard to permissions but the current documentation is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver16#Permissions + https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/integration-services-roles-ssis-service?view=sql-server-ver16
Specifically, you likely wish to assign `db_ssisoperator` to the users in question so they can

- Enumerate all packages.
- View all packages.
- Execute all packages.
- Export all packages.
- Execute all packages in SQL Server Agent.

But that may not be accurate depending on what your requirements are.

For those administering older 2012, 2014, maybe 2016, you had db_ssisadmin and I think that was it.

Comment: I have granted ssis_admin, but permission is still denied to write to the table. I followed the MS documentation, but still get the error. Was hoping for help. If not I will raise a ticket with MS.